# Custom scroll bar for Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use a plugin named **Jquery.mCustomScrollBar** to customize the scroll bars.

It's working except for an Object that displays a text file.

*Is there anyway to change the scroll bar on objects?  If not, what are some alternatives to embedding text files that would allow the scroll bar to be changed?*

Here's the link to the plugin

> http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Code:

```
<object class="notepad" data="../almost.asm" type="text/plain">
    <a href="#">No Support?</a>
</object>


<script>
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".notepad").mCustomScrollbar({
            scrollButtons:{
                enable:true
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does the object class have overflow: scroll?

Comment: It didn't, but when I tried nothing changed.

Comment: You can only have the container of the object to have the custom scroller eg:div over object but not the object itself

Comment: I went ahead and used Ajax to append everything. The custom scroll bar works perfectly now. How would I fix the format of the document though?

Comment: include the div and the class name that holds the content and preset the CSS in the CSS file